# WPF DataGrid Cannot Scroll even when there is a lot of data

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that when I load the data into it, I cannot scroll down

So this is how the `DataGrid` looks like
[image: DataGrid]

As you can see there are rows at the bottom that I can't see
[image: Rows Below the datagrid]
Even though when I try to put the highlight below I still can't see the rows below.

The `DataGrid` is auto-generated from a list. I have tried setting the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` & `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` but I still can't see the other data.

Here is my XAML code for the datagrid

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <DataGrid
                            x:Name="dgvAttendance"

                            Margin="0,20"
                            CanUserSortColumns="True"
                            CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedIndex="0" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionMode="Single" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="All" CanUserResizeRows="False" PreviewMouseWheel="DgvAttendance_PreviewMouseWheel" />

                        <Button
                            x:Name="btnExportExcel"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}"
                            Width="110"
                            ToolTip="Resource name: MaterialDesignRaisedLightDarkButton" Margin="15,10" Content="Export File" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="BtnExportExcel_Click"  />
                    </StackPanel>
```

There is also a button on the datagrid that I can't see

Here is my code that Loads the dataGrid

```
public void Main()
        {

            actuals = NewActual(@"C:\Users\IT\Desktop\Sample\SampleActual.dat");
            emps = GetEmp();

            var final = (from t1 in actuals
                         join t2 in emps on t1.ID equals t2.ID
                         where t1.ID == t2.ID
                         orderby t2.ID
                         select new
                         {
                             t1.ID,
                             t2.In,
                             t1.ActualLog
                         });

            dgvAttendance.ItemsSource = final.ToList();
        }
```

Any ideas why I am not able to scroll down and see the button below the `DataGrid`? Thanks

Comment: You can replace StackPanel with ScrollViewer or put your full xaml structure in ScrollViewer element

Comment: @Polly ill check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggestion from Polly

I just wrapped my StackPanel with a ScrollViewer so it looks like this

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" >

                        <DataGrid
                            x:Name="dgvAttendance"

                            Margin="0,20"
                            CanUserSortColumns="True"
                            CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedIndex="0" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionMode="Single" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="All" CanUserResizeRows="False" PreviewMouseWheel="DgvAttendance_PreviewMouseWheel" >
                        </DataGrid>

                        <Button
                            x:Name="btnExportExcel"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}"
                            Width="110"
                            ToolTip="Resource name: MaterialDesignRaisedLightDarkButton" Margin="15,10" Content="Export File" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="BtnExportExcel_Click"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!-- Stack for Datagrid Ends Here -->
                    </ScrollViewer>
```